# Point file pointer to buffer in memory rather than a file on disk

Tags: c, file-io, filestream

I am trying to have a `FILE*` in C that can write to a string buffer in memory rather than a file on disk.

I know that this functionality exists in the *fmemopen* function, but I am not running my program on Linux so this is not a solution for me. I have seen implementations for Mac as well, but I am programming for a Cortex M4 ARM processor, so I can't use this as well.

Any solutions out there that would potentially work when programming for a Cortex M4?

EDIT: To clarify, I need to end up with a `FILE` structure because I need to pass a `FILE*` into a library function I am using (libjpeg's `jpeg_stdio_dest()` and `jpeg_stdio_src()` functions) which specifically takes in a `FILE*` as an argument.

Comment: Just for the record `FILE*` is not a pointer to a file in disk, its a pointer to a `FILE` structure that holds the data required to handle a file descriptor with buffering support.

Comment: The fact that you are using an ARM processor isn't quite relevant to this question. More relevant would be the operating system you're targeting, since the operating system provides this kind of functionality, not the processor itself.

Comment: Now back to the question, why exactly you need that if you already have all the data prompty available in memory?

Comment: Good point. I edited my question accordingly, Havenard. And Paul92, I am not running any OS on the processor. There is no notion of a filesystem for the program loaded onto the processor (since I am not running an OS on it), which is why I must have the data promptly available in memory.

Comment: Is this as simple as using `sprintf()` rather than `fprintf()`?

Comment: I need to end up with a 'FILE' structure because I need to pass a `FILE*` into a library function I am using (libjpeg's `jpeg_stdio_dest()` and `jpeg_stdio_src()` functions) which specifically takes in a `FILE*` as an argument. It looks like `sprintf()` only writes to a string, so I don't think I could use this.

Comment: Surely libjpeg has functions that work on memory buffers?

Comment: Andrew, yes, that turned out to be the solution suggested by one of my friends. Thanks! For anyone who looks at this in the future, libjpeg provides a function called `jpeg_mem_src` that is used for this purpose. It was introduced in libjpeg8 though, so you can't use it with the precompiled libjpeg-turbo binaries.